# A* algorithm have a weird bug

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I try to write an A* algorithm for a game which I develop but sometimes it runs into a weird bug (The algorithm not complete yet).

I compare my algorithm result to https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/ 
result to see if I did it well and this is what I get:

my code: https://image.prntscr.com/image/k7FLFuzcScCPLEBMhwaM5Q.png
qiao code: https://image.prntscr.com/image/5IKMnlF9S-KXRORoQsPkvg.png

As you can see there are same buildings and distance, So why I get a different result? what am I missing?

Sorry for my English.

```
class AStar {
constructor(engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.engine.astar = this;
    this.dest = null;
    this.diagonal = false; // Can use diagonal? (7, 9, 1, 3)
    this.permission = null; // Source permission
}
nodePermission(node) {
    if (!this.engine.mapSettings.premissions.hasOwnProperty(node[0]))
        return false;
    if (!this.engine.mapSettings.premissions[node[0]].hasOwnProperty(node[1]))
        return false;
    return (this.engine.mapSettings.premissions[node[0]][node[1]] === this.permission);
} // return permission status (true or false)
getNeighborhoods(node) {
    let nodes = [];
    if (this.engine.player.position.x > 0 && this.engine.player.position.y > 0 && this.diagonal)
        nodes.push([(node[0] - 1), (node[1] - 1)]); // push 7
    if (this.engine.player.position.y > 0)
        nodes.push([node[0], (node[1] - 1)]); // push 8
    if (this.engine.player.position.y > 0 && this.engine.player.position.x < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeX && this.diagonal)
        nodes.push([(node[0] + 1), (node[1] - 1)]); // push 9
    if (this.engine.player.position.x > 0)
        nodes.push([(node[0] - 1), node[1]]); // push 4
    //nodes.push(node); // push 5
    if (this.engine.player.position.x < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeX)
        nodes.push([(node[0] + 1), node[1]]); // push 6
    if (this.engine.player.position.x > 0 && this.engine.player.position.y < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeY && this.diagonal)
        nodes.push([(node[0] - 1), (node[1] + 1)]); // push 1
    if (this.engine.player.position.y < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeY)
        nodes.push([(node[0]), (node[1] + 1)]); // push 2
    if (this.engine.player.position.x < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeX && this.engine.player.position.y < this.engine.mapSettings.mapSizeY && this.diagonal)
        nodes.push([(node[0] + 1), (node[1] + 1)]); // push 3
    if (nodes.length <= 0)
        return false;
    // Check block
    for (let i in nodes) {
        if (!this.nodePermission(nodes[i]))
            delete nodes[i];
    }
    nodes = nodes.filter(function(n){ return n !== undefined });
    return nodes;
} // return neighborhoods nodes (array of nodes)
nodeValue(node) {
    let result = [];
    // Distance between node and player
    result.push(
        Math.abs(node[0] - this.engine.player.position.x) + Math.abs(node[1] - this.engine.player.position.y)
    );
    // Distance between node and destination
    result.push(
        Math.abs(node[0] - this.dest[0]) + Math.abs(node[1] - this.dest[1])
    );
    // Sum of both
    result.push(result[0] + result[1]);
    this.engine.text.addText(result[1], 20*(node[0]-this.engine.map.mapConstructor.from.x), 20*(node[1]-this.engine.map.mapConstructor.from.y));
    return result;
} // return G, H, F (as array)
lowestNode(nodes) {
    let h = 0;
    let f = 0;
    let node = null;
    for (let i in nodes) {
        if (!nodes.hasOwnProperty(i))
            continue;
        let value = this.nodeValue(nodes[i]);
        if (h === 0 && f === 0) {
            h = value[1];
            f = value[2];
            node = i;
            continue;
        }
        if (value[2] < f) {
            f = value[2];
            h = value[1];
            node = i;
        }
        else if (value[2] === f && value[1] < h) {
            f = value[2];
            h = value[1];
            node = i;
        }
    }
    return nodes[node];
} // return the node with the highest priority to evolve
arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(let i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
searchForArray(needle, haystack){
    let i, j, current;
    for (i = 0; i < haystack.length; ++i){
        if(needle.length === haystack[i].length){
            current = haystack[i];
            for (j = 0; j < needle.length && needle[j] === current[j]; ++j);
            if(j === needle.length)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
findPath(node) {
    for (let id in this.engine.text.textList) {
        this.engine.text.deleteText(id);
    }
    let x = (this.engine.map.mapConstructor.from.x + node[0]);
    let y = (this.engine.map.mapConstructor.from.y + node[1]);
    let src = [this.engine.player.position.x, this.engine.player.position.y];
    this.dest = [x, y];
    this.permission = this.engine.mapSettings.premissions[x][y];
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    let openList = [src];
    let closedList = [];
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    while (openList.length > 0) {
        let current = this.lowestNode(openList);                            // Get the node with highest priority
        if (this.arraysEqual(current, this.dest))                           // If the algorithm reach to destination
            return this.reconstructPath(closedList, current);               // Reconstruct the path
        // Delete from openList
        let delIndex = openList.indexOf(current);                           // Get the index's node in array
        delete openList[delIndex];                                          // delete node by index
        openList = openList.filter(function(n){ return n !== undefined });  // remove empty value
        closedList.push(current);                                           // add node to closedList
        let neihberhoods = this.getNeighborhoods(current);                  // Get neighborhoods's node
        for (let i in neihberhoods) {
            if (!neihberhoods.hasOwnProperty(i))
                continue;
            if (this.searchForArray(neihberhoods[i], closedList))
                continue;
            if (!this.searchForArray(neihberhoods[i], openList))
                openList.push(neihberhoods[i]);
            if (this.nodeValue(current)[2] >= this.nodeValue(neihberhoods[i])[2])
                continue;
            closedList.push(neihberhoods[i]);
        }
    }
}
reconstructPath(closedList, current) {
    return;
    console.log('Found that');
    console.log(closedList);
    console.log(current);
    console.log('finish');
}
```

}

Comment: I didn't dive into your code, but when I implemented this (ages ago, different language), I generated some output with scores and numbers plotted onto the squares, and the possibility to pause between steps. That gave me a lot of insight in the things I did wrong, and apart from that, it was cool to watch once it worked.

Comment: @GolezTrol great an idea! i'll try it! thanks!

Comment: @GolezTrol I did it as you can see in the images above, it didn't give me any perspective why it is not working. can you suppose what makes that?

Comment: So on [jogdsl](https://prnt.sc/jogdsl) you were supposed to move to the left instead?

Comment: @GolezTroll in this specific image it works fine, I upload it to show you that it is working sometimes.

Comment: @GolezTrol Hey, sorry for bothering you again but I fixed my last bug and now I have something weirder... I edit the post, hope you can help me again :)

Comment: I will have to read your code at some point. ;-) But for now, just looking at the picture, it looks like you don't take the length of the start point to the 'current' square into account. To get to the '12' (left above the building), you would need 24 steps to get to that square.. Then you go right and add this node 13, which is actually 25+13. At that point, you need to investigate *all options* for 13 for backtracing, and it turns out that instead of going back to 12, you can also go up, arriving at a square which is 22+14. 22+14 is more efficient than 25+13, so that is the route to take.

Comment: So, [forgive my paint skills](https://postimg.cc/image/dg9ac7hon/), when you reached node A through the black path, you should look around and notice that going back through the red path is more efficient. The arrows indicate the way back from that node to the previous one. This is where the optimization is: Through all the nodes found, you have to find the *shortest* path back to the starting point, which can be done by keeping the distance-already-travelled for each node and choosing the best one.

Comment: Even when the algorithm is optimal, you may not get exactly the same result. There are many possible results that all have the same length. Which one you get depends which directions you explore first. But the total path length should be the same as for the other implementation, once you've solved this.